# Which shortcut can do this refactoring in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

Java code:

```
public void hello(MyFiles myFiles) {
     world(myFiles.getSourceFile(), myFiles.getTargetFile());         
}

public void world(String sourceFile, String targetFile) {
    // a very long method that uses 'sourceFile' and 'targetFile'
    System.out.println(sourceFile);
    System.out.println(targetFile);
}
```

I want to refactor it to:

```
public void hello(MyFiles myFiles) {
     world(myFiles);         
}

public void world(MyFiles myFiles) {
     File sourceFile = myFiles.getSourceFile();
     File targetFile = myFiles.getTargetFile()
    // a very long method that uses 'sourceFile' and 'targetFile'
    System.out.println(myFiles.getSourceFile());
    System.out.println(myFiles.getTargetFile());
}
```

How to do it all by some refactoring shortcut in Intellij-IDEA?

---

One possible solution:

1. Inline `world` method into `hello`:

   public void hello(MyFiles myFiles) {
       // a very long method that uses 'sourceFile' and 'targetFile'
       System.out.println(myFiles.getSourceFile());
       System.out.println(myFiles.getTargetFile());
   }
2. Extract the content of `hello` into a new method `world`, it will be what I want

But since method `world` is very long, when I inline it into `hello`, it may waste me sometime to choose the lines what I want to extract, so I'm looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I can see, the closest you can get is via 4 refactorings.

Use "extract method" (ctrl-alt-m) on this line, and call the new method `world`.

```
     world(myFiles.getSourceFile(), myFiles.getTargetFile());
```

Result:

```
public void hello(MyFiles myFiles) {
    world(myFiles);
}

private void world(MyFiles myFiles) {
    world(myFiles.getSourceFile(), myFiles.getTargetFile());
}
```

Next, use "inline" (ctrl-alt-n) on this line:

```
    world(myFiles.getSourceFile(), myFiles.getTargetFile());
```

result:

```
private void world(MyFiles myFiles) {
    // a very long method that uses 'sourceFile' and 'targetFile'
    System.out.println(myFiles.getSourceFile());
    System.out.println(myFiles.getTargetFile());
}
```

Now, use "extract variable" (ctrl-alt-v) on `myFiles.getSourceFile()` and `myFiles.getTargetFile()`, for all occurrences.

Result:

```
private void world(MyFiles myFiles) {
    // a very long method that uses 'sourceFile' and 'targetFile'
    String sourceFile = myFiles.getSourceFile();
    String targetFile = myFiles.getTargetFile();
    System.out.println(sourceFile);
    System.out.println(targetFile);
}
```

Please note that you can easily write a plugin to do this refactoring for you, in one step. That would be the recommended route if you are doing this refactoring often (or if it just annoys you...)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Refactor / Extract / Parameter Object. Close to what you need.